# Remove undef in an array of array in Perl

Tags: arrays, perl, arraylist, multidimensional-array

I am trying to remove the element from the array of array which has undef value.

I want the output to be:

```
@list = [
      [
        2,
        ""
      ],
      [
        4,
        ""
      ],
      [
        6,
        ""
      ],
      [
        8,
        ""
      ],
      [
        10,
        ""
      ],
    ];
```

This is what I have been trying to remove the undef from the array. I am grepping the defined element from the array, but its not working

```
use Data::Dumper;

my @list = [
  [
    undef,
    ""
  ],
  [
    2,
    ""
  ],
  [
    4,
    ""
  ],
  [
    6,
    ""
  ],
  [
    8,
    ""
  ],
  [
    10,
    ""
  ],
];

@list = grep defined, @list;

print Dumper(\@list);
```

Can someone please help ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: For a start, arrays are initialised with `@array = ( ... )`, not `@array = [ ... ]`. You have a one-element array and the single element is a reference to your actual array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

People often get lists and arrays confused in Perl. So calling an array variable `@list` is a really bad idea :-)

As I mentioned in a comment, you seem to be confused about how you populate an array in Perl. You either populate it with a list:

```
my @array = ( ... ); # Lists use parentheses
```

Or you create an *anonymous* array and store a reference to that array in a scalar variable:

```
my $array_ref = [ ... ]; # Anon array uses square brackets
```

Next, your array doesn't contain `undef` elements. Every element in your array is a reference to a two-element array. In one of those second-level arrays, the first element is `undef`. You're right to use `grep` to filter the array, but you need to look at the second-level array to do what you want.

So the code would look something like this:

```
my @array = ( ... );

@array = grep { defined $_->[0] } @array;
```

Note that I've switched to the block syntax of `grep`. This is the most commonly-used version and it's probably best to use that syntax.